# How to know the path to a specific file in a zip archive, without extracting it?

Tags: files, zip

I only know the filename but not its exact location. I would like to extract only that file from the archive. And I need to know its location in the archive.

Comment: `unzip -l archive.zip` will provide a listing. Use -h or --help on many/most commands for basic usage

Comment: @bdowning Thanks, and how do I get the path of a specific file from the list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`unzip` accepts wildcards and globs.  If you know the filename, then you could simply say:

```
unzip archive.zip "**/file_to_extract"
```

in order to extract the said file.

Answer (score 2):

As a synthesis of both comment and answer, you could proceed like this:

```
unzip -l archive.zip | grep "nameOfile"
./tmp/nameOffileponey
./ham/smoked/nameOfile
#identify the path of the file precisely in your archive if filtering gives you several result and then use 
 unzip archive.zip ./ham/smoked/nameOfile
```

This should work

Answer (score 1):

Mount the zip archive as a filesystem with [fuse-zip](http://fuse-zip.googlecode.com/). Then you can access files in it using any command you like.

```
mkdir foo
fuse-zip foo.zip foo
```

Then, to copy `needle.txt` from whichever subdirectory it's in:

```
find foo -name needle.txt -exec cp -p {} . \;
```

Or using the shell's recursive globbing (in bash, you need to run `shopt -s globstar` first; in zsh this works out of the box):

```
cp -p foo/**/needle.txt .
```

Unmount the filesystem when you've finished using it.

```
fusermount -u foo
```